# How to achieve this (image inside) with one flexbox container?

Tags: css, flexbox

How do you achieve this with only one flex container? Every box is a `<div>`.

As I unterstand flexbox its just for evenly sized childs?
Or do i have to wrap left and right into own divs?

Thx for the help

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item double">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item square">6</div>
  <div class="item double">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="item">9</div>
  <div class="item">10</div>
  <div class="item">11</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 700px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container div:not(:first-child) {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.item {
  color: white;
  background-color: #333;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.double  {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
}

.square  {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: You need to wrap left and right side, then you can either make those wrapper's flex containers or simply use display inline block. For a suggestion, post the code you have so far

Comment: Also, flexbox is not only for evenly sized children, though based on what you actually mean by that, they might still be

Comment: Thanks for your answer, with evenly sized I meant same heights I guess.

Comment: There is a more efficient solution than the one given, but here at SO we don't write up code for you, so post the code you want to use and we help make it work

Comment: I know you don't write code, I just want to get a hint or explanation if this solution I'm looking for is possible or anybody done this kind of flexbox.

Comment: Flexbox is designed for one-dimensional arrangements. You should use [CSS Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) for this.

Comment: Thanks Blaze, will look into grid right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve that one need to wrap the left and right group of elements, and make those both flex items and flex containers.

Here is a start how that can look like

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.container .wrapper {
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 70vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.container .item {
  color: white;
  background-color: #333;
  margin: 5px;
  flex-basis: calc(50% - 10px);
}
.container .item.square,
.container .item.double {
  flex-basis: calc(100% - 10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item double">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class=" item square">6</div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item double">7</div>
    <div class="item">8</div>
    <div class="item">9</div>
    <div class="item">10</div>
    <div class="item">11</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

One can of course use the middle wrapper as the 6:th item, as shown below, though it will be much simpler to maintain the code as done in the first sample

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.container .wrapper {
  flex: 1;
  flex-basis: 33.333%;
  min-height: 70vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.container .item {
  color: white;
  background-color: #333;
  margin: 5px;
  flex-basis: calc(50% - 10px);
}
.container .item.double {
  flex-basis: calc(100% - 10px);
}
.container .wrapper.square {
  color: white;
  background-color: #333;
  margin: 5px;
  flex-basis: calc(33.333% - 10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item double">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper square">6
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item double">7</div>
    <div class="item">8</div>
    <div class="item">9</div>
    <div class="item">10</div>
    <div class="item">11</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much for this solution, the second one looks really great, I fiddled around with flex-basis, but didn't think of using calc() there.